# Difference between Jetty 9 GzipFilter and AsynGzipFilter

Tags: jetty

What is the difference between the `GzipFilter` and `AsyncGzipFilter`? Which one should we be using?
With AsyncGzipFilter, some static files I've which were not being gzipped by the GzipFilter is now being gzipped.

Has chunked encoding got anything to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary difference is support for both the `asyncSupported` configuration requirements of the Servlet 3.1 spec (for servlets and filters), and also to better utilize the Async I/O features of the Servlet 3.1 spec.

We didn't want to change the original one to support async, as that would force your servlets to also be async.

Comment: Ok. I guess that doesn't explain why the GzipFilter is not working for some of the html pages.